# Exclude images from caching with Memcached / Dalli

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, caching, memcached, dalli

I've recently implemented caching with memcached heroku add-on using Dalli gem for my Rails application. What I find though is when deployed to Heroku, it also caches all my static assets including images, which quickly blows up my memcached size. A sample of heroku logs look like

```
cache: [GET /assets/application.css] fresh
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/sign-in-twitter.gif] fresh
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/ajax-loader.gif] fresh
app[web.1]: cache: [GET /assets/sign-in-facebook.gif] fresh
```

Specifically for index pages, the cache size increases by about 5MB for every different request. Is this behavior configurable? Can I configure memcached to cache only my fragment caches and not proactively cache every image in every page?

Answer (score 5):

Using dalli gem, In `config/environments/production.rb`:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = {
  :metastore    => Dalli::Client.new,
  :entitystore  => 'file:tmp/cache/rack/body',
  :allow_reload => false
}
```

The above configuration caches the metastore info in memcached but the actual body of the assets to the file system.

In `config/application.rb`:

```
if !Rails.env.development? && !Rails.env.test?
  config.middleware.insert_before Rack::Cache, Rack::Static, urls: [config.assets.prefix], root: 'public'
end
```

**Rack::Static usage:**
  The *Rack::Static* middleware serves up urls with a matching prefix to a root directory. Here I'm giving *config.assets.prefix* as my url prefix which defaults to *'/assets'*. This should serve any assets directly out of the *public/assets* directory instead of hitting *Rails::Cache*. This will only work if you run the *'rake assets:precompile'* in production, otherwise there will be no precompiled assets in *'public/assets'*.